# ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'FireBase.initializeApp': InternalError: No frame with index 39

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

When I try to connect Flutter project with firebase I face this problem `Chromeproxyservice: Failed to evaluate`
expression `'FireBase.initializeApp': Internalerror: No frame with index 39`.

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question! :)

Comment: I was faceing the same issue and what helped me is to addd Option parameters in the Firebase.Initialize method :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73226958

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and what helped me was the answer from @JanamMaharjan.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73226958

before :
`await Firebase.initializeApp()`

then changed to this to support Web-app/Chrome:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
  apiKey: "***", // Your apiKey
  appId: "***", // Your appId
  messagingSenderId: "***", // Your messagingSenderId
  projectId: "***", //
  storageBucket: "***", // Your projectId
 ),
);
```

Also need to add this to your Web/index.html
in the Header section:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase Auth SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```